# OutOfMemoryError when running the coreNlp tool

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I know there has been already many discussions about this issue on SO but none of them solve my problem. I have a file `test.txt` and I want to do some sentiment analysis on it. The format of the input file in one sentence per line. And I run the tool with following command:

```
java  -cp "../*" -mx1g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentPipeline -file test.txt
```

And it began to run and print the content of my file in a strange way. After a while, it throws this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I also tried:

```
java -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -cp "../*" -mx1g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentPipeline -file test.txt
```

But it still didn't work. 
BTW, I run the tool in command line instead of eclipse. So I think it is not about eclipse.
Could you please help me with this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Stanford CoreNLP - Java heap space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018382/using-stanford-corenlp-java-heap-space)

Comment: @SkyWalker No, it is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `-mx1g` to `-mx4g` in your command

Try with the following command:

```
java -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -cp "../*" -mx4g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentPipeline -file test.txt
```

### Suggestion#1:

You can permanently increase -Xms and -Xmx size

**Windows:**

```
SET _JAVA_OPTIONS = -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m
```

Linux:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m"
```

after that you can run the command simply

```
java -cp "../*" -mx4g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentPipeline -file test.txt
```

Hope it will solve your issue. If it not solve your problem, then increase the -Xmx size to `-Xmx6g`

### Suggestion#2:

You can use Java8. They use metaspace for heap. So, no heap space error will be occured there.

### Resource Link:

[how to increase java heap memory permanently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578123/how-to-increase-java-heap-memory-permanently)

### UPDATE:

Please check with following commands

```
java -cp "../*" -Xmx4g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPClient -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,dcoref -file test.txt
```

or you can use `-threads 1` in the command to make it single-threaded.

### Resource Link:

1. [Stanford NLP - OpenIE out of memory when processing list of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36431900/stanford-nlp-openie-out-of-memory-when-processing-list-of-files)
2. [CoreNLP Server Conf](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it doesn't solve my problem. And I said I didn't use Eclipse. So my question is totally different from that one. Please remove the duplicate.

Comment: Would you please check using `java -Xmx6144M -d64` @southdoor

Comment: Thanks for your update. Do you mean JDK8? Sorry I have used Java before. Please forgive my stupid question..

Comment: @southdoor yes JDK8

Comment: But when I run `java -version`, I got `java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)`. Does it mean the version is already 8?

Comment: @southdoor I have updated the answer. Would you please check and let me know the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

It means there is insufficient space to allocate the new object. Like in this case the garbage collector can't make space to accommodate a new object.